# The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, angular, api, entity-framework, crud

I'm writing an app that stores recipes and it's ingredients in two different db tables. I written this app using a tool that my company bought, it does basically writes the base of your code after you describe it in a .YML file (i hate it cause i can't debug it fully and I cannot oversee al the errors it generates, like in this case). I written a function to delete a recipe, but it fails when it first deletes all the ingredients tied to it (to not conflict with foreign keys)
So, my api has this function

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<DeleteRicettaByIdResponse>> DeleteRicettaById(Guid ricettaId, CancellationToken requestAborted)
    {
      // <custom:DeleteRicettaById>
            try
            {
                var ricettaDel = await _ricettaEntityRepository.FindAsync(ricettaId, requestAborted);
                var ingredienti = await _ingredienteEntityRepository.GetRicetta(ricettaDel, requestAborted);         
                foreach (var ing in ingredienti)
                {
                    await _uow.SaveAsync();
                    await _ingredienteEntityRepository.RemoveAsync(ing.Id, requestAborted);                  
                }

                await _ricettaEntityRepository.RemoveAsync(ricettaDel, requestAborted);
                await _uow.SaveAsync();
                return new DeleteRicettaByIdResponse
                {
                    Success = true
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new JsonResult(ex.Message) { StatusCode = 400, Value = ex.Message };
            }
            // </custom:DeleteRicettaById>
```

where uow is the unit of work (injected automatically by the tool so i have no power on it)
also, the repository functions like RemoveAsync is already written by the tool too,
i only wrote "GetRicetta" that gets all the ingredients of a recipe:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IngredienteEntity>> GetRicetta(RicettaEntity ricetta, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                return Entities.ToListAsync().Result.FindAll(i => i.RicettaEntityId == ricetta.Id);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new IngredienteEntity[] { };
            }
        }
```

It does work if the recipe has no ingredients tied to it, i tried to do uow.SaveChanges() randomly in some places but nothing...
The tool i'm using is made by an italian company so I don't think anybody know it, it's name is CodeGen by CodeArchitects

Comment: EF neither has nor needs a `uow` or `xxxRepository` classes. A DbContext already is a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. There's no EF code in the question you posted anyway, only calls to custom "repository" and "uow" classes. The call ` Entities.ToListAsync().Result` is a nasty bug - it loads the entire table in memory and is no better than `Entities.ToList()`. EF will start tracking all those objects. If you try to `Add()` another object with the same ID as one of those objects, you'll get the error you posted in the title, because EF will see that those IDs are already tracked

Comment: The `uow` classes are injected by the scaffolding tool my company use... 
`Entities.ToList()` does not exists only `ToListAsync()`

Comment: `ToList()` is an extension method over `IQueryable`. The whole point of using `ToListAsync()` is to avoid blocking. `ToListAsync().Result` blocks while trying to load the entire table in memory. `GetRicetta` is a bug, plain and simple. If you want to load all ingredients of a recipe, `context.Recipes.Include(r=>r.Ingredients).Where(r=>r.ID==recipeId).FirstAsync()` will load the recipe and its incredients. If you don't want the recipe, `context.Ingredients.Where(i=>i.RecipeID==recipeId).ToListAsync()`